# SafeArgs does not get generated

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, android-safe-args

I am using navigation components but cannot get the Args class generated so I can use it in my destination `Fragment` the following way:

```
private val myArgs by navArgs<MyDestFragmentArgs>()

// later in code access properties from args
username = myArgs.username
```

I see that `MySourceFragmentDirections` was generated so I assume the plugin is used correctly. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project in Android Studio but don't see any *Args classes generated.

My `nav_graph.xml` contains:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mySourceFragment"
    android:name="com.example.MySourceFragment"
    android:label="@string/nav_title_source"
    tools:layout="@layout/source_fragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_to_dest"
        app:destination="@id/myDestFragment">

        <argument
            android:name="username"
            app:argType="string" />

    </action>

</fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my `nav_graph.xml` did not have correct format (the `argument` element should be inside of the destination fragment, not inside an `action` element defined in the source fragment) as below:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mySourceFragment"
        android:name="com.example.MySourceFragment"
        android:label="@string/my_source_screen_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_source_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_dest"
            app:destination="@+id/myDestinationFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myDestinationFragment"
        android:name="com.example.MyDestinationFragment"
        android:label="@string/my_dest_screen_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_dest_fragment">

        <argument
            android:name="username"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
```